# Getting question marks in service response in codenameone

Tags: connection, codenameone

I am calling service using ConnectionRequest class and if i'm getting result in English i'm able to display it but if i'm getting response in Hindi at that time  getting as question marks(?) instead of Hindi text. and i'm using Devanagari Font to show the hindi text. is there any solution for this?

here is the code for how we are requesting?

adding parameters using Map like below.

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
map.add("Key","Value");
map.add("Key1","Value1");
etc..
```

then passing this `map` object to requestService method.

```
    private static Map<String, Object> requestService(Map<String, Object> data) {

    Connection connection = null;
    Dialog progress = new InfiniteProgress().showInifiniteBlocking();
    try {
        connection = new Connection(data);
        NetworkManager networkManager = NetworkManager.getInstance();
        networkManager.addToQueueAndWait(connection);
        networkManager.setTimeout(600000);
        if(connection.getResponseData() == null) {
            return null;
        }
    } finally {
        progress.dispose();
    }

    JSONParser jp = new JSONParser();
    try {
        Map<String, Object> result = jp.parseJSON(new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(connection.getResponseData()), "UTF-8"));

        return result;
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Connection Class:

```
private static class Connection extends ConnectionRequest {

    private final static char escapeS[] = new char[] { '"', '\\', '/', '\b', '\f', '\n', '\r', '\t' };
    private final static char escapeR[] = new char[] { '"', '\\', '/', 'b', 'f', 'n', 'r', 't' };
    private Map<String, Object> data;

    private Connection(Map<String, Object> data) {
        this.data = data;
        setFailSilently(true);
        setPost(true);
        setWriteRequest(true);
        setContentType("application/json");

        setUrl(serverUrl);
    }

    @Override
    protected void buildRequestBody(OutputStream os) throws IOException {

        String v = buildJSON(data);

        if(shouldWriteUTFAsGetBytes()) {
            os.write(v.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        } else {
            OutputStreamWriter w = new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8");
            w.write(v);
        }
    }

    private static String buildJSON(Map<String, Object> data) {
        StringBuilder json = new StringBuilder();

        buildJSON(data, json);
        return json.toString();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private static void buildJSON(Map<String, Object> data, StringBuilder json) {
        json.append('{');
        boolean first = true;
        Object value;
        for(String key: data.keySet()) {
            value = data.get(key);
            if(value == null) {
                continue;
            }
            if(first) {
                first = false;
            } else {
                json.append(",");
            }
            json.append('"').append(key).append("\":");
            if(value instanceof Map) {
                buildJSON((Map<String, Object>) value, json);
            } else if(value instanceof Collection) {
                buildJSON((Collection<Map<String, Object>>)value, json);
            } else {
                if(value instanceof Long || value instanceof Integer || value instanceof Double
                        || value instanceof Short || value instanceof Float) {
                    json.append(value);
                } else if(value instanceof Boolean) {
                    json.append((Boolean)value ? "true" : "false");
                } else {
                    json.append('"').append(escape(value)).append('"');
                }
            }
        }
        json.append('}');
    }

    private static void buildJSON(Collection<Map<String, Object>> data, StringBuilder json) {
        json.append('[');
        boolean first = true;
        for(Map<String, Object> e: data) {
            if(first) {
                first = false;
            } else {
                json.append(",");
            }
            buildJSON(e, json);
        }
        json.append(']');
    }

    private static String escape(Object any) {
        if(any == null) {
            return "";
        }
        String s = any.toString();
        if(s == null) {
            return "";
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < escapeS.length; i++) {
            s = replace(s, escapeS[i], escapeR[i]);
        }
        return s;
    }

    private static String replace(String s, char c, char r) {
        int i = s.indexOf(c);
        if(i < 0) {
            return s;
        }
        return s.substring(0, i) + "\\" + r + replace(s.substring(i + 1), c, r);
    }
}
```

please guide me to achieve this?

Comment: If you provide a sample of how you are requesting and ideally the encoding type I might be able to help. Notice that UTF-8 is usually recommended as encoding as it's universally supported.

Comment: added code of how we are requesting..

Comment: You seem to read UTF-8 but are you writing UTF-8 in the server?

Comment: no.. we are not encoding with UTF-8..

Comment: Ahem `new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(connection.getResponseData()), "UTF-8")`

Comment: actually i tried to read without "UTF-8" but still i'm getting as question marks(??) then i tried with "UTF-8"..

Comment: These aren't things you can try on and off. You need to consciously pick one encoding in all layers otherwise you will get this result. If you don't pick an encoding Java makes its own choice which is usually bad. You need to both write and read UTF-8. You need to check in the debugger through every stage to see where (and if) data gets corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

That means the result is encoded in a foreign language encoding and should be read using the correct hindi text encoding.

Comment: No shai.. after request the service when we got the response in server side console it is showing in hindi but in app we are getting as question marks..

Comment: But how do you parse that hindi text? Are you using a font that supports hindi?

Comment: I suggest opening this in the debugger both in the server and client and looking at the point where the String value is no longer correct.